# Running diskpart from system in windows sever 2022 - shows no disks

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2022, diskpart

I've inherited a system of VMs (AWS ec2) running on an older version of windows server. Due to software upgrades we need to also upgrade to windows server 2022.

One hang up I have is that the existing setup is using Group Policy Startup Scripts to initialize and partition disks that are attached when the VMs are created. This script uses `diskpart` to list the disks and then makes decisions based on the output of list disk. For example:

`diskpart /s list-disk.txt`

and `list-disk.txt` contains:

```
san policy=OnlineAll
list disk
```

Logging the output from this in the Startup script shows that its empty. But if I run the same command after logging in, it lists the excepted disks. Two hints I've found:

- Diskpart doesnt work in system in windows 2022 (2021 thread with no answers) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/568149/diskpart-doesnt-work-from-system-in-windows-2022
- If diskpart doesnt show any volumes it means that the MBR Partition Table or GUID Partition Table on the disk do not have any partitions listed in them. https://superuser.com/a/802204

To clarify, this works in an older version of windows server, but not in 2022. My backup plan is to test in 2019 as I think that will still support the upgrades Im trying to accomplish.

Update: This works on windows sever 2019

I am open to any suggested work-arounds, Thanks.

Comment: what does `diskmgmt.msc` telling you? because it is more or less a guide from diskpart

Comment: It tells me the same thing that diskpart list disk does after I'm logged in - It shows disks that correlate to my mounted EBS volumes.

Comment: did you reload the partion table and or rebooted the server?

Comment: I've rebooted several times to cause the Startup script to run.

Comment: "t is possible that the hardware, which is currently unknown, may no longer be supported. imho